# Using AWS: Is it possible to hide the traffic from amazon?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, cloud-computing

Assuming I use AWS to host a service with quite sensitive personal data, is it possible to hide traffic and stored data from amazon?

I would assume the answer is no. I think I need to provide all the keys, especially the private SSL-key, to amazon so that the service can run in the first place. This means that amazon could theoretically act as a man-in-the-middle and I see nothing I could do against that.

Comment: WRT `'I think I need to provide all the keys, especially the private SSL-key, to amazon'`:  No, you could fire-up an Amazon EC2 cloud server, create an SSL private key and CSR, get the CSR signed by a CA, and start running a web server with SSL using the private key and the cert, without the private key ever leaving the server.  But, that doesn't change the answer to your underlying question.  If Amazon wanted to, they could copy your private key any time, simply by doing a memory dump of your EC2 instance, which they can do whenever they want, because it's running on their hardware.

Comment: @mti2935 .. which, in the end, makes it possible for amazon to read the keys and therefore I have given that to them, correct?

Comment: OP, No I am not saying that Amazon *would* read your keys, I am saying that they *could* read your keys if they wanted to.  But it would be egregious and possibly unlawful.

Comment: Okay thank you, that's a very subtle the difference.